# How can I print without color with an HP Deskjet 990cse and Windows 7?

Tags: drivers, printing

I'm Using Windows 7 (32 bit) and an HP Deskjet 990cse Printer. I am using the standard HP 990c driver and the printer works fine with the exception of being able to print with only the black ink cartridge.

This driver uses colors from the color cartridge to 'enhance' the black - even if I set the printer to print in black and white only. This driver is wasting a lot of expensive colored ink instead of using the cheaper black ink. I'm printing a lot of text with embedded grey scale scans and so the this really matters.

Is there any way to stop the printer from wasting colored ink?  What I am really looking for is a way to completely turn off the use of color ink.  Perhaps a different HP Printer driver will allow this for the 990cse printer.  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What you are asking for is rather uncommon. Can you share with us what research you have already done and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Many Deskjet series doesnt have any options for Black Ink Only. Make sure your Deskjet 990cse has that feature.

Comment: CharlieRB, its Mike Johnson again.  I tried the HP 930 driver on advise from another forum post.  This seemed to solve the problem and now I am happily printing in gray scale w/o using the color cartridge.  I would bet your solution to use the HP 5550 series driver would work also. Thanks for all the help.  I am out.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there may be a way to get around this by using another compatible driver. I found this on the HP Support Forums - [Print black and white only (no grey scale)](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printing-Issues-Troubleshooting/Print-black-and-white-only-no-grey-scale/m-p/2888611/highlight/true#M55370). The solution is about 3/4 the way down, authored by HP Expert, Bob_Headrick.

> The Deskjet 5550 driver has an option for black only and should be
>   compatible with the Deskjet 990.  Try the following:  click Start,
>   Devices and Printers, right click on the Deskjet 990, Printer
>   Properties, Advanced, New Driver, Next,  Windows Update (wait a few
>   minutes for the list to refresh), select HP for the manufacturer,
>   select the "hp deskjet 5550 series (HPA) (HP)" , Next, Finish, Apply. 
>   This will change the name of the pritner, you may want to rename the
>   printer back to Deskjet 990....

I don't have this printer, so I can not verify this will work. But it may get you where you need to be.